# Laravel passport returning home page instead of apis response

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) for response  of token  in api

I followed this blog for my code:
https://blog.logrocket.com/laravel-passport-a-tutorial-and-example-build/

I am getting this error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target
> class [Auth\UserAuthController]

[image]

[image]

as ulitmator suggested I added  `x-www-form-urlencoded` but am still getting this Laravel screen in response.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it's looking for the literal class: `Auth\UserAuthController`. That isn't the full namespace. You're looking for it at: `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserAuthController`. This looks like an issue with how your routing file is configured. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing and https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers or whichever version you're using of laravel. There's different ways of doing things.

I generally organize my routes by specifying the full namespace something like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\UserAuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController;

// ...

Route::post('/register', [UserAuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('/login', [UserAuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::apiResource('/employee', EmployeeController::class)->middleware('auth:api');
```

See also https://litvinjuan.medium.com/how-to-fix-target-class-does-not-exist-in-laravel-8-f9e28b79f8b4

Up until Laravel 7, the RouteServiceProvider.php file had the following code:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
Route::middleware('web')
    ->namespace($this->namespace)
    ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

What this does is tell Laravel to load the routes in routes/web.php, using the web middleware and the App\Http\Controllers namespace. This, in turn, means that whenever you declared a route using the string syntax, Laravel would look for that controller in the App\Http\Controllers folder.

In Laravel 8, the $namespace variable was removed and the Route declaration was changed to:

```
Route::middleware('web')
    ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

This means that starting in Laravel 8, when you declare your routes using the string syntax, Laravel isn’t going to look for your controller inside App\Http\Controllers.

While I wouldn't recommend it, you can also add the namespace back manually to behave like older laravel by adding 3 lines of code into your RoutesServiceProvider.php file:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers'; // Add this line


public function boot() {
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function() {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace) // Add this line
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace) // Add this line
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    });
}
```

But generally the laravel 8+ way of doing things is to use `use` and `::class` within the routes file, and specify the full namespace to the controller. It looks like you're following a tutorial built for older laravel. If using laravel 8+, please use the laravel 8+ way of organizing your routes file instead.

**Edit:**

In Postman you'd make a post to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register
```

And specify the fields:
name, email, password, and password_confirmation.
(note in the screenshots you provided you did not show a password and password_confirmation, hence you're failing validation)
Make sure the email uses valid email address syntax.
Make sure the password and password_confirmation match.
Make sure you're using x-www-form-urlencoded as per the tutorial.  You may use form-data if you so wish, but then Content-Type MUST be blank so postman can fill the multipart/form-data boundaries for you.

For the **name**, I used: a
For the **email**, I used: a@b.com
For the **password**, I used: a
For the **password_confirmation**, I used: a

[image: postman]

You can also debug this in case you run into validation errors:

Debugging option 1: Edit your UserAuthController.php file,
Instead of using:

```php
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);
```

Use instead a try-catch like so:

```php
try {
    $data = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);
} catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e){
    return response($e->getMessage(), 400);
}
```

Debugging option 2: Instead of using a try-catch, you can also specify an accept header in your postman request. Normally when validation fails within laravel it will redirect you to the previous page and send the errors there. Without displaying them, you'll just see the laravel welcome page `/`. But if you specify an `Accept` header for `application/json`, laravel will understand you're looking for a json response. In postman your headers would look like this:
[image: headers]

Note also if you're going to send form-data, you MUST NOT set a Content-Type header. Make sure to uncheck it so you're not sending it. If you choose x-www-form-urlencoded, it will automatically set a Content-Type header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is fine if you're going to use x-www-form-urlencoded. But if you select form-data, this will be a mismatch and you'll run into issues. For form-data, since you cannot specify a boundary and separate the fields with the boundary, you should leave the Content-Type blank. This will allow postman to automatically set the boundaries for you.

Assuming it works, you'd see an entry in your users table:

[image: users table]

Comment: @ultimator i am using Laravel v9.41.0 (PHP v8.1.9) and now as u  sugessted  i edited RoutesServiceProvider.php  & api.php file still i am not getting any responce from api except that home screen as in the screenshot i added can u help me with that

Comment: You need to add Content-Type: application/json header and Accept: json. I'm not sure about exact values but postman will help you.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanJaved i am not sure where i should add that can u explain

Comment: @jisaks You're more than likely running into validation errors, which if it fails validation, it will redirect to the previous page. Through the api, this doesn't make much sense, and you'd see the `/` page, hence the welcome page you're seeing. I'd first make sure your controller is running. Go to UserAuthController.php and change the register method to instead return right away like so: `return 'Yay I work';` If that works, you can remove that line. You're probably then running into validate issues.

Comment: @jisaks Make sure in postman you're using x-www-form-urlencoded, not form-data. See my updated answer.

Comment: @jisaks on postman with body tab you see headers tab. That's where we can add request headers. And I believe for Laravel to do API related things we need to pass Accept: json header and maybe Content-Type: application/json header as well.

Comment: @MuhammadHassanJaved The endpoint expects Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded since the $request reads from the parameters in that way. The Content-Type: application/json which you suggest is for other types of endpoints which read the Raw data, where you'd supply a json object. Since we're not supplying a json object, Content-Type: application/json won't work with the endpoints in the tutorial. If you go through the screenshots in the tutorial, they're all using Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Specifying the Accept parameter doesn't hurt, but doesn't help either.

Comment: @Ultimater  i want to pass data as form-data  insted of  x-www-form-urlencoded in post man what changes must i do

Comment: i have tryed as u asked using x-www-form-urlencoded still getting same issue

Comment: @Ultimater i am usin larvel 9 so showuld i add this line `->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));`  or the 3 lines

Comment: @jisaks  what Muhammad meat is , add the header `accepts: application/json` so the api returns a json error instead of redirecting you and showing a html response. If you cant change it in the `headers` tab, disable it and add a new "accepts" header

Comment: @jisaks please read from the **edit** in my post. You need to specify a `password` and `password_confirmation` field in your post which you are not showing in your screenshot. `'password' => 'required|confirmed'` means it uses `password` and `password_confirmation`. The laravel page you're seeing means your validation is failing and it's redirecting to previous page and not showing you error messages due to it being the default page. Please edit `UserAuthController.php` and surround the validation code with a try-catch and output the error as shown in my post.

Comment: @jisaks For the headers, make sure you don't specify the Content-Type, because postman will autofill this for you. For the post-data it needs a boundary and postman will autofill this for you. If you attempt to specify `multipart/form-data`, you can't place boundaries between fields unless you send a raw request. Postman will do this all for you if you don't specify the Content-Type. Also instead of using a try-catch, you can also put a `Accept` in the headers and then put `application/json` and it will send back validation errors rather than redirect back to the default laravel page.

Comment: If changing from x-www-form-urlencoded on the body to form-data, postman will automatically add a Content-Type to the headers. Please go into the headers and uncheck the header it adds then you should be able to use form-data.

Comment: `LogicException: Unable to read key from file file://C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\app\Providers/../secrets/oauth\oauth-private.key`   @Ultimater i am getiing this error

Comment: @jisaks You need to run `php artisan passport:install` it should store an `oauth-private.key` and `oauth-public.key` file to the location it's looking. As it appears you're on windows, you might need to use php.exe instead of php, etc.

Comment: @Ultimater i tryed `php artisan passport:install`    then i got `file_put_contents(C:\Users\jisa\pregent-app\app\Providers/../secrets/oauth\oauth-public.key): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory`  to solve that i cleared cache using `php artisan optimize:clear` still getting same error

Comment: @jisaks I don't know why it looks for your keys there. On my system, on laravel passport 11.3, it looks for the keys in the storage directory instead. You might be on an older passport. But otherwise, you should be able to create the directory structure manually: C:\Users\jisa\pregent-app\app\secrets\oauth\ then retry running the command.

Comment: in composer file i have  "laravel/passport": "^11.3",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250521/discussion-between-ultimater-and-jisa-ks).